# Problem with code about loops and final sequence in string

Tags: python, loops

If I want to define a sequence results of the form PIPPPINNNIPPPPPPPPPPINN

for the following planets elements: AXDDCCCCSSDFQWEAACCCXXX, porty: ASDF, y, Nick: ZXCV

Where P and N are the initials of the player leading the other, and I is the positioner when both players are tied.

The code with which you started the resolution is this:

```
porty = input('').upper()
nick = input('').upper()
planetas = input('').upper()
resultado=""
cont1=0
cont2=0
for resultado in planetas:
  for n in nick:
    if resultado == n:
      cont1 = cont1+1
for resultado in planetas:      
  for p in porty:
    if resultado ==p:
      cont2 = cont2+1

    if (cont1 > cont2):
      resultado +="P"
    else:
      if (cont1 > cont2):
        resultado +="N"
      else: 
        resultado +="I"
print(resultado)
```

Comment: `resultado` is used both as a loop variable and as the final result. I think you should use a separate loop variable (`planeta`?). The way this is written `resultado` is overwritten each time through the loop.

Comment: Also it would help if you said what the problem is you are experiencing. Do you get the wrong output? If so what is it? Does the loop not terminate?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence that you expect does not match the inputs you provided, but here is a solution nonetheless :

```py
player1_letters = "ASDF"
player2_letters = "ZXCV"
planets = "AXDDCCCCSSDFQWEAACCCXXX"

result = ""
for planet in planets:
    if planet in player1_letters:
        result += "P"
    elif planet in player2_letters:
        result += "N"
    else:
        result += "I"

assert result == "PNPPNNNNPPPPIIIPPNNNNNN", result
# example by OP : PIPPPINNNIPPPPPPPPPPINN
```